# PHP - return the same page with changes

Tags: php, html

I have html page where you can insert some information and then submit this form, which will change information in database. I do it normally, that submit button call php file in server.
But what I want, is that this php file will return to me the same html page of which I sent request, with modified changes. e.g: there will be "Database update successfully" text added etc.
How can I do it without AJAX ?

Thanks

Comment: Can you show code that you're using currently?  If I understand correctly, you have two PHP files that you want to merge into one and, on that one, conditionally show/hide text based on the state of the input?

Comment: have a hidden field that is blank initially. when u submit modify it with something like 'updated'. in the php you can pick up the state (initial or post submit) and act accordingly in the php. so basically one php file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the PHP file, do a call to the header() function to redirect the user. For example:

```
header('Location: url.php');
```

To change the content of that page they are redirected to, you could pass something in the URL that your page will check for. For example:

```
header('Location: url.php?submitted=1');
```

There are other ways to implement this, but this seems the most straightforward to me. Note that you don't want to call header() until the end of your submission page.

Comment: I think this sounds as best solution. thanks. But what do u think about AJAX? when to sue it?

Comment: Well, Ajax is of course an option and may be desirable if you're trying to avoid a page-based site/application. However, it does have limitations. For example, you can't (in any way which I'm aware) do a file upload via Ajax. However, if your form data is simpler (i.e. text fields, select lists, etc.), then Ajax is still an option. In such a case, you'd direct the action of the form submission to a JavaScript function. That function would get the values from the form and then use an appropriate API (e.g., jQuery) to send the values to a PHP script. You could have

Comment: the PHP script then return JSON which a JavaScript callback would inspect and then use to determine how to update the page.

Answer (score 0):

Use [POST/REDIRECT/GET](http://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/The-Authorize-Net-Developer-Blog/Handling-Online-Payments-Part-6-Preventing-Duplicate-Submissions/ba-p/11168)

Excerpt:

> 1. The user submits the form
>
>    This is pretty straight forward. The user completes the form and submits it by pressing the submit button or enter on their keyboard.
> 2. We store the form data in a session
>
>    After processing the data we discover an error so we need to redisplay the form with an error message but we also want to populate
>      it with their data so they don't have to refill the entire form just
>      to fix potentially one little mistake. So we store their data in a
>      session ($_SESSION). Session variables carry over from page-to-page
>      for as long as the session is valid or until they are deleted. This is
>      an ideal place to put their information since redirecting will cause
>      their information to be immediately discarded by the server.
> 3. We redirect the user back to the same page using a 303 redirect
>
>    Once we have saved the user's information in their session we need to redirect them back to the same page. In order for this to work
>      properly we need to use a 303 redirect. This means we need to send a
>      303 header with our redirect. A 303 redirect will cause the browser to
>      reload the page without the initial HTTP POST request to be
>      resubmitted. This includes when the user uses the back or refresh
>      buttons.
> 4. We re-populate the form using the data stored in the session
>       When the page is sent to the user we re-populate it with their information we saved in their session.

Answer (score 0):

Only by generating the whole page in CGI first, unless you go through some horribly convoluted method of getting value of one of the fields to be set to document.innerHTML or something like that in Javascript. But you'll go through hell to get the quoting issues resolved. Use AJAX, it was created for precisely this purpose and exactly to avoid the utter hell associated with what you need.

Alternatively: the "modified piece" of the page may be an iframe, and you can set the `target` attribute of the form, so that the PHP returns only the iframe content.

Comment: Yes, I know that AJAX is great for it. But I worked before in ASP.NET and there was thsit kind of stuff normally, to refresh page with modified content. So I was just interested is there is smth similar in PHP